# Do the webview in flutter cached web page?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to cache the web page I display in flutter webview so to improve my performance, no need to reload the page. Is that available? and can I implement it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**flutter_inappwebview(former flutter_inappbrowser)** 
Has parameter `cacheEnabled`. Default value is true. 
`cacheEnabled` sets whether the WebView should use browser caching

**flutter_webview_plugin community version** 
Has parameter `appCacheEnabled` to enable cache

```
WebviewScaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    url: widget.url,
    clearCache: true,
    appCacheEnabled: true,      
);
```

**webview_flutter official version** 
Do not provide parameter , you can check with Android Source code
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/webview_flutter/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/webviewflutter/FlutterWebView.java

Default cache mode depend on  `iOS WKWebView` and `Android` `WebView` 
Default cache mode of `Android WebView` is `LOAD_DEFAULT`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#LOAD_DEFAULT 
Default cache usage mode. If the navigation type doesn't impose any specific behavior, use cached resources when they are available and not expired, otherwise load resources from the network.

Comment: I used webview_flutter and every time I open the webview, it take few seconds to load it. As you say, the cache usage mode is default but seem like it not work. Should I change to flutter_inappwebview or flutter_webview_plugin? @chunhunghan

Comment: You can do some simple test. I only find performance compare between Native WebView and Flutter WebView.

Comment: And which one is better? @chunhunghan

Comment: Do you mean open WebView slow or WebView is already opened but open url is slow?

Comment: For open url. no clear winner. In some website fast but in some may slow.

Comment: Thanks you. I change to flutter_webview_plugin to make sure it use app cached.

Comment: @hoangquyy for webview_flutter -> await webViewController.clearCache();